# Need help with this physics problem on Conservation of Energy

Tags: energy-conservation

A basketball player makes a jump shot. The **0.570-kg** ball is released at a height of **1.90 m** above the floor with a speed of **7.10 m/s**. The ball goes through the net **3.03 m** above the floor at a speed of **4.23 m/s**. What is the work done on the ball by air resistance, a nonconservative force?

Comment: first of all find out the initial velocity before passing through the net and after passing through the net...then use the work energy theorem in this case..

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please note that our homework policy asks you to show your own effort when seeking help with your homework.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).